# Как повторять условный оператор до тех пор пока не будет выполнена функция if?

Tags: python

```
print("text")
a = str(input("Введите 2-й номер."))

if a == "89857900082":
    print("Все верно!")
elif a != "89857900082":
    print("Именно 2 номер, не 1 и не 3.")
```

#я хочу получить от пользователя правильный ответ, в случае не верного ответа нужно вывести elif но не заканчивать цикл а запустить его заново, и только после выполнения if продолжить код.

Подскажите пожалуйста)

Comment: Оберните это все циклом. Если ответ верный, цикл остановить, если не верный, заново спросить число...

Comment: выражение "пока не будет выполнена функция if" не имеет смысла. Во-первых, if не функция. А во-вторых, if "выполняется" каждый раз, когда встречается в коде. То, что ты имеешь в виду, говорится словами - "пока не будет выполнено условие"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оберните ваш if в цикл и добавьте флаг правильного ответа

```
neverno = True

while neverno:
    a = str(input("Введите 2-й номер."))
    if a == "89857900082":
        print("Все верно!")
        neverno = False
    else:
        print("Именно 2 номер, не 1 и не 3.")
```

Или без отдельного флага

```
a = 0

while a != "89857900082":
    a = str(input("Введите 2-й номер."))
    if a != "89857900082":
        print("Именно 2 номер, не 1 и не 3.")
print("Все верно!")
```

Comment: `input` ведь и так возвращает строку

Comment: @ZxNuClear Стилистика автора сохранена :) А так, да, str не нужен

Comment: огромное спасибо! все работает.

Answer (score 2):

Или так

```
a = '89857900082'

while input("Введите 2-й номер: ") != a:
    print("Именно 2 номер, не 1 и не 3.")
else:
    print('Все верно')
```